# A tv series with a meteorite

Tags: story-identification, horror

Recently, someone told me about a series where a meteorite hits the earth. When a team goes to investigate it, they find out that the plants around the impact have mutated. After a while the team itself starts to undergo the effects.

It really sounded like a good series but he couldn't remember the name, anyone that can help me?

Comment: [Evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_(2001_film))?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211957/movie-where-heroine-wakes-up-to-a-mirror-image-enemy-that-copies-her-every-move (which is newer but has an OP-provided answer)

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure it was a series?  This sounds like the basic plot to the new Alex Garland movie, *[Annihilation](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2798920/)*.  Did your friend happen to mention if the team was all female?

(From comments, below):

> I think he said there was a guy too in the team. Because after a while that guy went crazy, he thought there were worms in his stomach or something like that.

There was an earlier team of guys who went crazy and apparently killed each other, whom the female team were tracking.  They left a couple of a videos behind, in one of which:

> One member of the male team cut another's stomach open and revealed the intestines were moving of their own accord.

Comment: He surely said it was a series, I think he said there was a guy too in the team. Because after a while that guy went crazy, he thought there were worms in his stomach or something like that.

Comment: @Jonas That still lines up with Annihilation.  I'll edit my answer since this involves spoilers.